# Run command in other folder

Tags: php, exec

I have a php script that should run a command located in a certain subfolder, in another subfolder.

The command is in folder `Cmd`, and should be executed in folder `1.6.2`. So first I switch to the `1.6.2` directory, and then I use a relative path to call the command:

```
exec("cd 1.6.2");
exec("..\Cmd\sencha app build production");
```

But this throws the error that the directory couldn't be found, because the second `exec` still executes in the main folder, where the calling index.php file resides.

The [php manual on `exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) doesn't provide any possibility to execute in another directory. Am I missing something here?

The current system is a Windows, but I have to make it portable because it may be executed on linux in the future.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud How do you program mouse clicks into a PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the working directory first

e.g.

```
chdir('/path/to/1.6.2');
exec("sencha app build production");
```

Comment: I could, but this still leaves me without a way to go into the 1.6.2 folder first. The `sencha` command requires me to call it from the 1.6.2 folder or else it throws "Command must be called from within a framework folder".

Comment: Perhaps the PHP Change Directory command might help? http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php : chdir( "/path/to/1.6.2" ); exec('sencha'); I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the directory within the same exec() command.
like so: `exec("cd 1.6.2 && Cmd/sencha app build production");` depending on your actual folder structure. I'm just guessing)